# localdb does not create database file if its missing

Tags: localdb, sqlexception

I use this connection-string:

```
Server=(localdb)\\MyInstance;Timeout=30;Database=MyDB;AttachDBFilename="C:\Temp\MyDB.mdf";Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Once I run a migration from my code using

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Normally, this "simply" works. The db is not just migrated, it is also getting its file created for it.

However, on the device of a colleague, the same code results in this error message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Cannot attach the file 'C:\Temp\MyDB.mdf' as database 'MyDB'."
```

If I give *my* database files to my colleague and he places them in the appropiate directory first, everything works as expected and the other code in that program can access everything in it, as it would do normally.

We've tried different paths and always checked the file-system rights. LocalDB or entity-framework (I'm not sure which is normally responsible for creating database files) simply won't create the database-file if it's missing on his device.

Are there any switches causing this? Can I explicitly tell localdb with the connection-string that it should create the database file?

Comment: Are you both running the exact same Localdb version?

Comment: Just checked it, we both have 13.1.4001.0